# how to iterate an instance of such an object?

Tags: python, linked-list, iterator

I would need to iterate an instance of this class without having to implement something else in this class.

I thought about making a deep copy of an instance and then `.pop()` the elements. However, this copy is too expensive for my program to work.

Does anyone have a simple enough idea?

```
class Frame:
    '''
    attributes :
    - data :  
    - next : next Frame or None

    Dependencies : None
    '''
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.data=x
        self.next=None

class Linked_list:
    '''
    class for a linked list

    attributes :
    - head : Frame or None

    methods :
    - is_empty() : return true is the list is empty, false otherwise
    - append(x) : add the data x at the head 
    - pop() : if the linked list is not empty, pop the head, else do nothing and return None
    - print() : print the list

    Dependencies : class Frame
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head is None

    def append(self,x):
        new_head = Frame(x)
        new_head.next = self.head
        self.head = new_head

    def pop(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return None
        x=self.head.data
        self.head=self.head.next
        return x

    def print(self):  # fonction d'affichage de la liste
        print('Liste chainees= ',end='')
        current=self.head
        while current:
            print(current.data,end=' ')
            current=current.next
        print()
```

Comment: What you want to do while iterating? I see in the `print` method you are already iterating and printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite your `print` method into a generator function, I guess:

```py
def gen(your_list):
    current=your_list.head
    while current:
        yield current.data
        current=current.next
```

Then you could iterate through the data, for example:

```py
a = Linked_list()
a.append(1)                                                    
a.append(2)
a.append(3)           

for i in gen(a):
    print(i)
```